# Qt 6.2: Menus Truncated initially on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qtwidgets

In my Qt 6.2.0 application menus are truncated on initial display after starting the program on Windows 10. On the Mac the problem did not occur yet.

[image]
This only happens once per Menu (once per Edit, once per Mode etc...) - but not for all Menus. It seems not to depend on the size of the Menu. Its always the last entry that will be truncated and in all cases the second last entry is a separator.
If i choose the menu a second time it will be fully displayed:

[image]

If menus are rebuilt in response to a language change the problem occurs once again per menu.#

Is this a known problem or has anyone else seen this?
How can i avoid this?

Comment: In Qt6 they changed the way device pixel ratio works on Windows when the system defined zoom is not 100 %. In Qt5 device pixel ratio was always 1 on Windows. In Qt6, if you have system defined zoom 150 % then DPR is 1.5, If you have 125% then it is 1.25 etc. And as I found there are several bug related to this change. I would expect these problems you describe to appear when zoom is bigger than 100 %. And in that case you may try to play around with `https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy`... I do not say it will solve your issue, but it is worth trying

Comment: Yes - Zoom is unequal to 100% on the machines where this occurs. I will investigate. Thanks for that answer so far.

Comment: Please, spend a few moments and report it as a bug to Qt https://bugreports.qt.io They should definitely address this soon.

Comment: I already posted this in the forum (https://forum.qt.io/topic/131646/menus-truncated-initially-on-windows-qt-6-2) but yes, i will file a bug report.

Comment: See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98347

Comment: Thanks. By reporting bugs, you help to make Qt better.

Comment: @ V.K. I agree - but the last time i filed Qt Bugs they've been fixed several years afterwards )-:

Comment: without reporting, they would not be fixed at all

Comment: I my experience, they do not get fixed at all (I have been waiting for a fix in Qt5 for 5 years now, the bug has been classified as "Critical" which does not seem to be of importance) - they just start a new branch (Qt6) and more bugs file in without the old bugs being fixed.

Comment: @jens: Did you try the fix in my answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I found a better fix:

```cpp
QGuiApplication::setHighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy(Qt::HighDpiScaleFactorRoundingPolicy::Floor);
```

Comment: Sadly, this setting introduces a number of new problems. See https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-98347

Answer (score -1):

This line fixes the problem:

```
QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("Windows"));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this reverts to Windows95 style, which looks ugly...